# Setting locale in moment.js not working despite using the locale file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

There is a `setLocale` method in a dependency of a project, and I call this method from the project on locale change. However, the locale doesn't seem to change.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/de'; 

export const setLocale = locale => {
    console.log(`Locale to be set: ${locale}`)
    moment.locale(locale);
    console.log(moment.locale())
};
```

[Output in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK2ur.png)

I'm using `moment-js v2.26.0`in the dependency and `2.24.0` in the main project.

Same happens if I set locale explicitly.

However, changing the locale works in the main project works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this issue by importing `momentjs` and locales in the following way:

```
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
```

From [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/)

> To save the step of loading individual locales (i.e. just load them all), import the `moment/min/moment-with-locales` module instead.

This of course doesn't explain why importing just one file fails.

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation

> Note: There is a bug that prevents moment.locale from being loaded.
>
> ```
> var moment = require('moment'); 
> moment.locale('cs');
> console.log(moment.locale()); // en
> ```

use workaround below

> ```
> var moment = require('moment'); 
> require('moment/locale/cs');
> console.log(moment.locale()); // cs
> ```

Comment: Well, I *am* importing the locale file (`import 'moment/locale/de'`) and the file is in `node_modules`.

Comment: @KarloSpacapan, i see, sorry, then it is not your case, my bad